# Send-proxy fails on ssl-passthrough haproxy

Tags: docker, ssl, haproxy, traefik

I want to use ssl-passthrough on Haproxy to route traffic to traefik.
This works, however I want to know the ip of who is making the request. The haproxy docs say I have to use send-proxy. This works for http, but not for https. Traefik has proxy-protocol enabled.

Firefox reports `SSL_ERROR_RECORD_OVERFLOW_ALERT`

Chrome says `ERR_SSL_PROTOCOL_ERROR`

Traefik logs show:

```
msg="http: TLS handshake error from haproxy_ip:51206: tls: oversized record received with length 22617"
```

Did I miss something in my config?

My haproxy config:

```
global
    log /dev/log    local0
    log /dev/log    local1 notice
    chroot /var/lib/haproxy
    stats socket /run/haproxy/admin.sock mode 660 level admin expose-fd listeners
    stats timeout 30s
    user haproxy
    group haproxy
    daemon

defaults
    log     global
    option  tcplog
    mode    tcp

    timeout connect 1s
    timeout client  20s
    timeout server  20s
    timeout client-fin 20s
    timeout tunnel 1h
    #option httplog
    #option dontlognull
    #timeout connect 5000
    #timeout client  50000
    #timeout server  50000
    errorfile 400 /etc/haproxy/errors/400.http
    errorfile 403 /etc/haproxy/errors/403.http
    errorfile 408 /etc/haproxy/errors/408.http

    errorfile 500 /etc/haproxy/errors/500.http
    errorfile 502 /etc/haproxy/errors/502.http
    errorfile 503 /etc/haproxy/errors/503.http
    errorfile 504 /etc/haproxy/errors/504.http

frontend http_front
    bind *:80
    option http-server-close
    option forwardfor
    default_backend http_back

backend http_back
    balance roundrobin
    server private_server private_ip:80 send-proxy


frontend https_front
    bind *:443
    mode tcp
    option tcp-check
    default_backend https_back

backend https_back
    balance source
    mode tcp
    option ssl-hello-chk

    server private_server private_ip:8080 send-proxy
```

The Traefik config:

```
debug = false

logLevel = "DEBUG"
defaultEntryPoints = ["https","http"]

[entryPoints]
  [entryPoints.http]
  address = ":80"
    [entryPoints.http.redirect]
    entryPoint = "https"
  [entryPoints.https]
  address = ":443"
  [entryPoints.https.tls]
  [entryPoints.http.proxyProtocol]
    trustedIPs = ["127.0.0.1/32", "private_ip"]
    #insecure = true
[retry]

[docker]
endpoint = "unix:///var/run/docker.sock"
domain = "dartsresults.nl"
watch = true
exposedByDefault = false
```

Comment: Can you share the part of your Traefik configuration where you set up the endpoint and proxy protocol?

Comment: @NickRamirez I added the Traefik config

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This should be "https" in `[entrypoints.https.proxyProtocol]`, as in:

```
[entryPoints.https]
  address = ":443"

  [entryPoints.https.tls]
  [entryPoints.https.proxyProtocol]
    trustedIPs = ["127.0.0.1/32", "private_ip"]
```

Info about using tables in TOML: https://github.com/toml-lang/toml#table